# Running API tests in Teamcity build step

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, teamcity

I have a Spring Boot Maven app. There is a bunch of API tests using `RestAssured`, inside the project. These tests are not marked as `@SpringBootTest`, therefore when running them, the context of the application is not raising so to make tests pass the application must be up and running before.

I'm creating a `Teamcity` build in which I want to:

1. Start the app
2. Run RestAssured tests
3. Create an artifact

I'm using an Agent with maven installed.
The question is:

> How can I create a build step where I run the application on a defined port and then run api tests
>   against it?

What I've tried is creating such build steps:

1. Command line: `mvn spring-boot:run & sleep 50s mvn test`
2. Maven step/command line: `mvn clean package -DskipTests`

I thought the spring boot application will start and tests will be ready to start after some time. On successful step 1 I create an artifact.

The problem is that the build step is never exited because of spring boot app running (blocking terminal).

Comment: Why are you not using the testing capabilities of Spring boot ?

Comment: I wanted to set up CI/CD for the friend's project, so I didn't really want to change anything on the code side - but probably I'll have to when there will no teamcity magic I can do.

Comment: I strong encourage you to use the testing capabilities of Spring boot cause it's much simpler and also running in the IDE....